# Can I use two different models for the POST and GET of a single RESTful Url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've looked elsewhere on SO for an answer to this question, but can't find one.

I'm building an MVC Web API that will, in part, kick off processes on a remote machine.  As of right now, a POST to "blah.com/Process" will save some initialization data to the database and instruct a windows service to begin operating on it.  A GET request to "blah.com/Process/{Id}" will retrieve the current progress of the process.

These two controller actions use two different models.  The POST accepts a model that contains parameter information, which the GET (since it's used to report progress, and I couldn't care less about the parameters) does not return.  Is this a violation of RESTful design?  Should I be using two different URLs, or would *that* be a violation of REST?  As I understand it, the data being transferred should represent the current state of the process, which in my mind it does in both cases.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the responses.  I feel more secure in my approach now.  :)

Comment: If the GET URL returns the progress of the process, why not create a URL similar to `http://blah.com/Process/{id}/Progress`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer):

> Conforming to the REST constraints is generally referred to as being "RESTful". If a service violates any of the required constraints, it cannot strictly be considered RESTful.

Without going into complex detail, these constraints are:

- Client–server
- Stateless
- Cacheable
- Layered system
- Code on demand (optional)
- Uniform interface

Neither case in your description violates these principles. Do what makes the most sense to the consumers of the API, keeping the whole as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it's not a violation of REST. But even if it were, if it's working for you it may still be ok, as long as it makes sense for your design.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen GET and POST methods combined to the same URL. It is acceptable to do so, and not a violation of RESTful design.